# how restart Jquery function if not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I let my form alert re-start once the user re-click the button if the input still empty

What I made :
after the click it will check if the inputs empty will stop the code and show alert. but once the alert appeared if I re-click the button again its not work again!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function requierd()
        {
  $('#allrequierd').addClass("animated");
  $('#allrequierd').addClass("shake");
  $('#alertDanger').removeClass("hide");
  setTimeout( "$('#alertDanger').fadeOut();", 4000);
 }
 
 function pass()
        {
  $('#alertDanger').addClass("hide");
  $('#alertsuccess').removeClass ("hide");
  $('#visitorFullName').val('');
  $('#visitorPhoneNumber').val(''); 
  $('#visitorEmail').val(''); 
  $('#visitorMsg').val('');     
  $('#alertsuccess').addClass ("animated");
  $('#alertsuccess').addClass ("bounceIn");
  setTimeout( "$('#alertsuccess').fadeOut();", 4000);
 }
 
 $('#sendContactMsg').click(function ()
        {
  var visitorFullName = $('#visitorFullName').val();
  var visitorPhoneNumber = $('#visitorPhoneNumber').val();
  var visitorEmail = $('#visitorEmail').val();
  var visitorMsg = $('#visitorMsg').val();
  var visitorCallMethod = $('#visitorCallMethod').val();
  
  var dataString = 'visitorFullName='+visitorFullName+'&visitorPhoneNumber='+visitorPhoneNumber+'&visitorEmail='+visitorEmail+'&visitorMsg='+visitorMsg+'&visitorCallMethod='+visitorCallMethod;

                if(visitorFullName==''||visitorPhoneNumber==''||visitorEmail==''||visitorMsg=='')
         {
       requierd();
  }else{
   // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "functions/sContactus.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(result){
//   alert(result);
    if (result == "Success") {
//     alert("DONE");
     pass();
     
    }else {
     alert("Sorry Try Again")
    }
   }
   });
   }
   return (start);
 
 });
    
   



// END jquery
});
```

Comment: Name the function and call it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fire the alert the first time, your `#alertDanger` is getting the `.fadeOut()` which will apply inline `display:none` style to that element. You're not removing that inline style at any point, and in fact you're also not adding back the "hide" class either, so your `#alertDanger` will remain hidden.

What you should do is "reset" the alert div after you fade it out:

```
function removeAlert() {
    $('#alertDanger').fadeOut();
    $('#alertDanger').addClass("hide").css("display","block");
}
```

And in your required() function:

```
 setTimeout( removeAlert, 4000);
```